# "404 Not Found" when viewing swagger api-docs when using swagger-springmvc (now springfox)

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to configure swagger in my spring project, but hitting Hitting "http://localhost:8080/api-docs" says "404 Not Found".

**Maven Dependency**

```
<dependency>            
  <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>           
  <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>                   
  <version>0.8.2</version>      
</dependency>
```

**SwaggerConfig.java File**

```
package com.ucap.swagger;

import com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.JacksonScalaSupport;
import com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.SpringSwaggerConfig;
import com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.SpringSwaggerModelConfig;
import com.mangofactory.swagger.configuration.SwaggerGlobalSettings;
import com.mangofactory.swagger.core.DefaultSwaggerPathProvider;
import com.mangofactory.swagger.core.SwaggerApiResourceListing;
import com.mangofactory.swagger.core.SwaggerPathProvider;
import com.mangofactory.swagger.scanners.ApiListingReferenceScanner;
import com.wordnik.swagger.model.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mangofactory.swagger")
public class SwaggerConfig {

    public static final List<String> DEFAULT_INCLUDE_PATTERNS = Arrays.asList("/news/.*");
    public static final String SWAGGER_GROUP = "mobile-api";

    @Value("${app.docs}")
    private String docsLocation;

    @Autowired
    private SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig;
    @Autowired
    private SpringSwaggerModelConfig springSwaggerModelConfig;

    /**
     * Adds the jackson scala module to the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter registered with spring
     * Swagger core models are scala so we need to be able to convert to JSON
     * Also registers some custom serializers needed to transform swagger models to swagger-ui required json format
     */
    @Bean
    public JacksonScalaSupport jacksonScalaSupport() {
        JacksonScalaSupport jacksonScalaSupport = new JacksonScalaSupport();
        //Set to false to disable
        jacksonScalaSupport.setRegisterScalaModule(true);
        return jacksonScalaSupport;
    }

    /**
     * Global swagger settings
     */
    @Bean
    public SwaggerGlobalSettings swaggerGlobalSettings() {
        SwaggerGlobalSettings swaggerGlobalSettings = new SwaggerGlobalSettings();
        swaggerGlobalSettings.setGlobalResponseMessages(springSwaggerConfig.defaultResponseMessages());
        swaggerGlobalSettings.setIgnorableParameterTypes(springSwaggerConfig.defaultIgnorableParameterTypes());
        swaggerGlobalSettings.setParameterDataTypes(springSwaggerModelConfig.defaultParameterDataTypes());
        return swaggerGlobalSettings;
    }

    /**
     * API Info as it appears on the swagger-ui page
     */
    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo(
                "News API",
                "Mobile applications and beyond!",
                "https://helloreverb.com/terms/",
                "matt@raibledesigns.com",
                "Apache 2.0",
                "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
        );
        return apiInfo;
    }

    /**
     * Configure a SwaggerApiResourceListing for each swagger instance within your app. e.g. 1. private  2. external apis
     * Required to be a spring bean as spring will call the postConstruct method to bootstrap swagger scanning.
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public SwaggerApiResourceListing swaggerApiResourceListing() {
        //The group name is important and should match the group set on ApiListingReferenceScanner
        //Note that swaggerCache() is by DefaultSwaggerController to serve the swagger json
        SwaggerApiResourceListing swaggerApiResourceListing = new SwaggerApiResourceListing(springSwaggerConfig.swaggerCache(), SWAGGER_GROUP);

        //Set the required swagger settings
        swaggerApiResourceListing.setSwaggerGlobalSettings(swaggerGlobalSettings());

        //Use a custom path provider or springSwaggerConfig.defaultSwaggerPathProvider()
        swaggerApiResourceListing.setSwaggerPathProvider(apiPathProvider());

        //Supply the API Info as it should appear on swagger-ui web page
        swaggerApiResourceListing.setApiInfo(apiInfo());

        //Global authorization - see the swagger documentation
        swaggerApiResourceListing.setAuthorizationTypes(authorizationTypes());

        //Every SwaggerApiResourceListing needs an ApiListingReferenceScanner to scan the spring request mappings
        swaggerApiResourceListing.setApiListingReferenceScanner(apiListingReferenceScanner());
        return swaggerApiResourceListing;
    }

    @Bean
    /**
     * The ApiListingReferenceScanner does most of the work.
     * Scans the appropriate spring RequestMappingHandlerMappings
     * Applies the correct absolute paths to the generated swagger resources
     */
    public ApiListingReferenceScanner apiListingReferenceScanner() {
        ApiListingReferenceScanner apiListingReferenceScanner = new ApiListingReferenceScanner();

        //Picks up all of the registered spring RequestMappingHandlerMappings for scanning
        apiListingReferenceScanner.setRequestMappingHandlerMapping(springSwaggerConfig.swaggerRequestMappingHandlerMappings());

        //Excludes any controllers with the supplied annotations
        apiListingReferenceScanner.setExcludeAnnotations(springSwaggerConfig.defaultExcludeAnnotations());

        //
        apiListingReferenceScanner.setResourceGroupingStrategy(springSwaggerConfig.defaultResourceGroupingStrategy());

        //Path provider used to generate the appropriate uri's
        apiListingReferenceScanner.setSwaggerPathProvider(apiPathProvider());

        //Must match the swagger group set on the SwaggerApiResourceListing
        apiListingReferenceScanner.setSwaggerGroup(SWAGGER_GROUP);

        //Only include paths that match the supplied regular expressions
        apiListingReferenceScanner.setIncludePatterns(DEFAULT_INCLUDE_PATTERNS);

        return apiListingReferenceScanner;
    }

    /**
     * Example of a custom path provider
     */
    @Bean
    public ApiPathProvider apiPathProvider() {
        ApiPathProvider apiPathProvider = new ApiPathProvider(docsLocation);
        apiPathProvider.setDefaultSwaggerPathProvider(springSwaggerConfig.defaultSwaggerPathProvider());
        return apiPathProvider;
    }


    private List<AuthorizationType> authorizationTypes() {
        ArrayList<AuthorizationType> authorizationTypes = new ArrayList<>();

        List<AuthorizationScope> authorizationScopeList = newArrayList();
        authorizationScopeList.add(new AuthorizationScope("global", "access all"));

        List<GrantType> grantTypes = newArrayList();

        LoginEndpoint loginEndpoint = new LoginEndpoint(apiPathProvider().getAppBasePath() + "/user/authenticate");
        grantTypes.add(new ImplicitGrant(loginEndpoint, "access_token"));

        return authorizationTypes;
    }

    @Bean
    public SwaggerPathProvider relativeSwaggerPathProvider() {
        return new ApiRelativeSwaggerPathProvider();
    }

    private class ApiRelativeSwaggerPathProvider extends DefaultSwaggerPathProvider {
        @Override
        public String getAppBasePath() {
            return "/";
        }

        @Override
        public String getSwaggerDocumentationBasePath() {
            return "/api-docs";
        }
    }
}
```

**ApiPathProvider.java file**

```
package com.ucap.swagger;

import com.mangofactory.swagger.core.SwaggerPathProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

public class ApiPathProvider implements SwaggerPathProvider {
    private SwaggerPathProvider defaultSwaggerPathProvider;
    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    private String docsLocation;

    public ApiPathProvider(String docsLocation) {
        this.docsLocation = docsLocation;
    }

    @Override
    public String getApiResourcePrefix() {
        return defaultSwaggerPathProvider.getApiResourcePrefix();
    }

    public String getAppBasePath() {
        return UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromHttpUrl(docsLocation)
                .path(servletContext.getContextPath())
                .build()
                .toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String getSwaggerDocumentationBasePath() {
        return UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromHttpUrl(getAppBasePath())
                .pathSegment("api-docs/")
                .build()
                .toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String getRequestMappingEndpoint(String requestMappingPattern) {
        return defaultSwaggerPathProvider.getRequestMappingEndpoint(requestMappingPattern);
    }

    public void setDefaultSwaggerPathProvider(SwaggerPathProvider defaultSwaggerPathProvider) {
        this.defaultSwaggerPathProvider = defaultSwaggerPathProvider;
    }
}
```

Also, there is a property file in resources folder which contains:

> app.docs=http://localhost:8080

When I am hitting "http://localhost:8080/api-docs" it neither gives any result nor any error, On google Rest the response code is 404.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

The version that you're using (0.8.2) is a very old version of [springfox](http://springfox.io). You should try and move to the latest released version, which is [2.0](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/).

To answer your questions specifically.

1. Move to the most recent pre-2.0 version. Change the version of swagger-spingmvc in your pom to 1.0.2
2. The swagger configuration is vastly simplified in later releases. Change your `SwaggerConfig` to look like this.

```java
@Configuration
//Hard to tell without seeing all your configuration, but optionally, 
//add EnableWebMvc annotation in case its not working
@EnableWebMvc 
@EnableSwagger
//Assuming your controllers are in this package
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.ucap.swagger") 
public class SwaggerConfig {

    public static final List<String> DEFAULT_INCLUDE_PATTERNS 
             = Arrays.asList("/news/.*");
    //Unless you specifically want this group, I would recommend ignoring this
    public static final String SWAGGER_GROUP = "mobile-api"; 

    @Autowired
    private SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig;



    @Bean
    public SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin customImplementation(){
        return new SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(this.springSwaggerConfig)
          .includePatterns(DEFAULT_INCLUDE_PATTERNS);
    }
}
```

3. You don't need your path provider any more.
4. You no longer need the property file

Comment: code line " return new SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(this.springSwaggerConfig)
          .includePatterns(DEFAULT_INCLUDE_PATTERNS);" throwing a compile time error as "The method includePatterns(String...) in the type SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin is not applicable for the arguments 
 (List<String>)